# conversion of Eigen::matrixXd to Double

Tags: c++, eigen

I have been trying to reconstruct the input data fed to my RBM program written in C++ with the aid of Eigen library. But in order to keep the matrix elements of the reconstructed matrix into some specific range, i need to apply a sigmoid function to those. 
When i do so i get a conversion error and i don't know the way round it.

Here is my Sigmoid function computed in an header file:

```
       double sigmoid(double x) 
            {
                return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
            }
```

And here is how i compute the reconstruction:

```
         MatrixXd V;
         double well[36];
         Map<MatrixXd>( well, V.rows(), V.cols() ) = V;
         V = sigmoid(H * result3Eigen.transpose() + onesmat*result2Eigen.transpose());
```

At last here the error message i get when compiling the code:

```
        error C2664:'utils::sigmoid':cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Eigen::MatrixXd' 
        to 'double'
```

Thank you for any hints in solving the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to apply a function to each element of an Eigen matrix, you can use the [`unaryExpr`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7) function:

```
V = my_matrix.unaryExpr(&sigmoid);
```

This will run the `sigmoid` function on each element of the Eigen matrix `my_matrix`, and then return another matrix as the result.